# LaPlace Transform of a step function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the function $f(t)=\begin{cases} 0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;t<\pi  \\t-\pi \;\;\;\;\; \pi\leq t \leq2\pi \\ 0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; t\leq 2\pi          \end{cases}$

Find the laplace transform of this function. What I did was I wrote it in terms of the step function $f(t)=u_{\pi}(t)[t-\pi]+u_{2\pi}(t)[\pi-t]$ So therefore I set up a integral of $\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} e^{-st}(t-\pi) +\int_{2\pi}^{\infty}e^{-st}(\pi-t)$ The result I end up with is $\dfrac{-2\pi e^{-2\pi s}}{s}-\dfrac{2e^{-2\pi s}}{s^2}+\dfrac{e^{-\pi s}}{s^2}$ However the book ends up with a different answer which I get when I only consider $\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} e^{-st}(t-\pi)$, but not the other. Why are they considering 1 integral when there is in fact 2 that need to be evaluated. Or is the way I defined my step function wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper boundary of your 1st integral should be $\infty$ instead of $2\pi$.

Effectively the part above $2\pi$ in your first integral cancels out with the 2nd integral, resulting in a single integral.

Comment: But the function "lives" in the interval of $[\pi,2\pi]$ So shouldn't this be a piece wise function?

Comment: It already is a piece wise function. It is only the part $[π,2π]$ where it needs to be integrated. However, you rewrote it in a form that is not piecewise, but is generally true. That means you have to integrate on $[0,\infty)$. It is still only the part on $[π,2π]$ where the function is different from $0$ though.

Comment: Could I technically just integrated the $f(t)$ without rewriting it on the interval $[\pi,2\pi]$

Comment: Yes. That is what the book did.